# Create a SharePoint List from Datatable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, datatable

How we can create a SharePoint List from Data-table.

Comment: Could you please give us more information how you want to create it?

Comment: try code from here http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93ac2dca-9ac4-41d2-9349-21fb068619bf/how-to-convert-a-datatable-to-splist?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious

Comment: I have a DatatTable object which stores all data of Table. So my task is to make Sharepoint Custome List from this DataTable.

Comment: what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Actually my problem is resolved from given above link. Thanks for advice

Comment: Good to know, it solve the issue. i added that into as reply so mark it as answer so others get benefited.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little tricky if you have different datatypes in your datatable.

But an example, using only text fields could be something like this.

```
/* Create datatable */
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Columns.Add("Test1");
      dt.Columns.Add("Tets2");

      using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://myurl"))
      {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
          SPList newList = null;

          try
          {
            Guid newListGuid = web.Lists.Add("TempList", "This is my temp list, it will be removed when used", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
            newList = web.Lists[newListGuid];

            if (newList != null)
            {
              /* Loop through the datatable and add columns to the list */
              foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
              {
                newList.Fields.Add(dc.ColumnName, SPFieldType.Text, false);
              }

              /* Update the list to get the new fields */
              newList.Update();

              /* Populate the list from the datatable */
              SPListItem newItem = null;
              foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
              {
                /* Create a new item in the list */
                newItem = newList.AddItem();

                foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                  newItem[dc.ColumnName] = row[dc].ToString();
                }

                /* Save the item to the list */
                newItem.Update();
              }
            }
          }
          catch
          {
            /* Do some logging */
          }
          finally
          {
            if (newList != null)
            {
              newList.Delete();
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Source: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93ac2dca-9ac4-41d2-9349-21fb068619bf/how-to-convert-a-datatable-to-splist?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious